# Material-ui icons create blank screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, icons

I repeatedly installed material-ui and material-ui icons, but whenever I try to use material-ui icons, it gives me a blank screen as well as a lot of errors.

Header.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import "./Header.css"
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';

function Header() {
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <h1 className="header_important">header</h1>
            <PersonIcon />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Error Message:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    React 2
    node_modules bundle.js:50231
    React 17
    js index.js:7
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 3
react.development.js:1476
```

```
The above error occurred in the <MuiSvgIconRoot> component:

../../../node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-699e6908.browser.esm.js/withEmotionCache/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50231:66
SvgIcon@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1166:82
PersonIcon
div
Header
div
App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries. react-dom.development.js:20085
```

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    React 2
    node_modules bundle.js:50231
    React 17
    js index.js:7
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 3
react.development.js:1476
    React 2
    withEmotionCache emotion-element-699e6908.browser.esm.js:34
    React 17
    js index.js:7
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 3
```

The screen is just white. If I remove the `<PersonIcon />` from Header.js, it renders fine and it gives no errors.

Edit: Package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "tinder-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you also share your package.json file? I was just curious about the package versions you're using. Or Is it possible to create a CodeSandBox project by reproducing this problem?

Comment: I added the package.json file.

Comment: Try changing `function Header() { ... }`  to `const Header = () => {  ... }`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are using Material UI V4 and V5 simultaneously
uninstall all these packages

```
   "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.5",
```

and reinstall the Material V5 (Because you are using React 17.02)
then install

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm install @mui/icons-material
```